# nodejs, how to make socket connection close to backend server after some timeout time

Tags: node.js

I am implementing web server using express module, the web server communicates with the backend server to get the data and send to UI.

Now if due to some reason the backend server does not send any data, then TCP connection does not get closed. How I can implement connection to backend server close after some timeout period?

I am not using socket.io module.

Regards,
-M-

Comment: The connection shouldn't disconnect on its own.  You are experiencing some connection problem of some kind.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Socket` you can close the server connection using:

```
socket.on('timeout', function () {
   socket.close();
});
```

You can also:

- [socket.setTimeout()](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback)
- [socket.setKeepAlive()](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay)